# Using regular expression in Python to generate a list

Tags: python, regex, list, variables, python-2.7

I have a small script which is used to produce an image with predefined font and text. I would like to change it to use multiple fonts to render the same text e.g. letter `A` in 5 fonts. I am defining my fonts list as :

`fonts    = [ 'Georgia', 'Consolas', 'Arial'` ]

and then I use it in :

```
for item in enumerate(fonts) :
 ...
```

I would like to generate the list with all e.g. Times New Roman family fonts. I was trying to generate the list with regular expression but with no luck. I do not really know how to embed it in the list (with quotes, with `/` in beginning and end, etc.)

I have tried something like this :  `fonts = [ '/^.Times.*$/' ]` and this `fonts = [ '/Times.*/g' ]` but with no success.

Seond problem arose when I wanted to use 3 words fonts like `Luicida Console Regular`, then I got this error :

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.py:46: PangoWarning: couldn't load font "Luicid
a Console 40", falling back to "Sans 40", expect ugly output.
  pangctx.show_layout (layout)
```

looks like the script is getting only two words from the font name.

**EDIT**

```
def main ():
    surface = cairo.ImageSurface (cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    context = cairo.Context (surface) 
    source  = context.get_source ()
    font    = sys.argv[1]

    fonts    = [ 'Georgia', 'Consolas', 'Arial',  'Lucida Console', 'Times New Roman' ]
    output  = sys.argv[2]
    text    = sys.argv[3]

    background = cairo.SolidPattern (255, 255, 255)
    context.rectangle (0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    context.set_source (background)
    context.fill ()

    pangctx = pangocairo.CairoContext (context)

    layout  = pangctx.create_layout () 
    layout.set_width ((WIDTH - 2 * PADDING) * pango.SCALE)
    layout.set_single_paragraph_mode (True)
    layout.set_wrap (pango.WRAP_CHAR)

    size    = 40 * pango.SCALE
    spacing = 10 * pango.SCALE
    markup = ''
    for index, item in enumerate(fonts):
        print index, item
        markup  += '<span font="'+ item +'" size="' + str(size) + '" letter_spacing="' + str(spacing) + '">' + text +'</span>'
    layout.set_markup (markup)
    pangctx.update_layout (layout)

    context.new_path ()
    context.move_to (PADDING, PADDING)
    context.set_source (source)
    context.set_source_rgb (0, 0, 0)

    pangctx.show_layout (layout)
    surface.write_to_png (output)
```

**EDIT** 
seems that this is still a bug in pango [launchpad link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-client/+bug/734689)

Comment: Why do you believe that a regex is valid there, and what the hell is "Luicida Console"?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams "Luicida Console Regular" is a font - at least on my system(Win7). What do you mean by ' regex is valid there ' ?

Comment: No it isn't. What led you to believe that a regular expression will be used by whatever you're passing it to?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sorry, then. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of all available font names:

```
fonts = [f.get_name() for f in layout.get_context().list_families()]
```

To leave only those fonts that match a regular expression e.g., to select fonts that have `mono` or `space` in the name (case-insensitive):

```
mono_fonts = filter(re.compile(r'(?i)mono|space').search, fonts)
```

btw, it might be more readable to use string formatting instead of `+` operator:

```
markup += '<span font="{}" size="{}" letter_spacing="{}">{}</span>'.format(
                       item, size, spacing, text)
```

The `font` attribute seems to work for me:

```
>>> import cairo
>>> import pango
>>> cairo.version
'1.8.8'
>>> pango.version_string()
'1.29.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

First, there seems to be a spelling error in your try. It's "Lucida", not "Luicida"

Second, it seems you are using Pango? Why not use that to list all available font variations? See e.g. the [pygtk tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pygtktutorial/pango/).

Edit: Looking at your code, and the reference for the [Pango Markup Language](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/pango-markup-language.html), it seems that "font" is not a valid attribute. Try "font_family" instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Although I still get this Times New Roman problem - script is not reading `Roman` word - [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Hdj6iNyb)

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the complete code, or at least the Pango calls that you use?

Comment: You might mean `font_desc` instead of `font_family`. Though `font` and `font_desc` produce identical results.

Answer (score 1):

Filter the list `fonts` based on the regex match.

```
import re
r = re.compile("Times.*")
for item in enumerate(f for f in fonts if r.match(f)):
    ...
```

In your case you could just check for string containment:

```
for item in enumerate(f for f in fonts if f.contains("Times")):
    ...
```

You'll need to provide more details for the second error.

Answer (score 1):

This will yield a list of all the fonts that begin with "Times" in your fonts list:

```
timesFonts = filter(lambda x: re.match(r'^Times.*', x), fonts)
```